# iOS UIScrollview not scrolling full height in freeform

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, scrollview

I've followed this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg) step by step to create a ScrollView inside a view controller.

In the tutorial the view controller is set to freeform size and set to a height of 1,000. My issue is that for some reason the view refuses to show anything higher than a height of 700. Any content placed after the height of 700 is not loaded in the simulator.

Could someone please tell me why? and how can I fix it?

I've followed the tutorial step by step.

Comment: The tutorial is perfect, It should have worked. May be you have missed something. Can you debug, like what is your scrollview and view's height?

Comment: The scrollview height is at 680, should this also be set to the 1000? I assumed the scrollview height would adjust automatically to the view's height. The view's height is at 1000

Comment: In the tutorial, a scroll view has been place in view controller's view, and another new view is placed on scrollview, Have you set that new view's height as 1000? and new view's width same as scrollview's width?

Comment: You can set the scrollview content size programatically. Please ensure it suppose to set in viewDidApppear                                                                      override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.scrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView!.contentSize.width, height: 1000.0)

    }

Answer (score 0):

Please check your scroll view's constraints. Is your scrollview's bottom hugging with Bottom Layout Guide/SuperView? It should as below,

[image]

Comment: Ok, so as you suggested in your comment, I've made the scrollview width equal to its child view. The scrollview's bottom is hugging with bottom layout guide, however the top is hugging with top layout guide. In your screenshot the top is hugging with superview, could you explain how you got this?

Comment: top layout guide/superview, I do not think that is the issue. Can you please create a small demo project and send me project link, So that I can download and check, Because its weird if you follow the tutorial it should work.

Comment: You have said earlier you scrollview height is 680, So your viewcontroller's view height is also 680, right?

Comment: Ok, I'll create the demo as soon as I can. And sorry, what I meant to say was 980, not 680. The view controller's height is 1000 and the inner view's height is also 1,000

Comment: Here's the link for the demo project after following the tutorial step by step: https://github.com/AllenGuerra/scrollViewiOS

Comment: There is no scroll view on the project. :-)
Nothing in storyboard.

Comment: Anyway, I'm adding that by myself.

Comment: can you check it now: https://github.com/AllenGuerra/scrollviewios. Sorry, I didn't see your comment. I had removed the repo

Comment: https://github.com/AllenGuerra/scrollviewios I've download the code. I've run in both simulator and device, Scrolling is working perfectly. :-p
Can you please run the code by yourself?

Comment: I don't have a device to test it on at the moment, however it definitely doesn't work in the simulator. Like I said, anything I place after the height of 700 doesn't load in the simulator. Perhaps it's some other configuration in Xcode itself? Do you have any idea what it might be?

Comment: I've tried in multiple laptop, with multiple devices and simulator. every where  your code is working and it should be, I do not know why it is not working on your simulator. You do know how to scroll in simulator, right?

Comment: You mean scrolling in the simulator is different than scrolling anywhere else? I just drag the scrollbar on the side with my mouse...

Comment: I updated Xcode to the latest version and now the scrollview works in both simulator and in my device. I guess that was the problem all along.

Comment: Great. Finally.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview size suppose to be same as parent view size. 
You can set the scrollview content size programatically.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{ 
 self.scrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView!.contentSize.width, height: 1000.0) 
}
```